# jQuery replace hyphens with spans for blogger date header

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I'm looking to customize the default date header in blogger with jQuery.

The original output is:

```
<h2 class='date-header'>2011-01-20</h2>
```

I want to wrap the YYYY, MM, and DD in spans so I can manipulate them as child nodes.

The result would be:

```
<h2 class='date-header'><span class="dhy">2011</span><span class="dhm">01</span><span class="dhd">20</span></h2>
```

Each attempt of mine adds extra tags so it's a nested mess.

Anybody have a good solution?

Comment: I've used this code more successfully:    $("a").each(function() {
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/[_-]/g," "));
});    from   http://chirale.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/character-substitution-on-jquery/. Still not happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice functional solution:

```
$('.date-header').html(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    var classes = ['dhy', 'dhm', 'dhd'];
    $(this).html($.map(txt.split(/-/), function(val) {
        return $('<span/>', {'class': classes.shift()}).text(val)[0];
    }));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/WdRAw/

Comment: Then please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the gray checkmark left to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it always has the same format of YYYY-MM-DD then you could use split to get the elements, loop through them, create your output HTML then add that as the HTML of the h2.

```
$(function()
{

   $(".date-header").each(function()
   {

      var arrDate = $(this).text().split("-");

      var strOut = '<span class="dhy">'+arrDate[0]+'</span>-';
      strOut+= '<span class="dhm">'+arrDate[1]+'</span>-';
      strOut+= '<span class="dhd">'+arrDate[2]+'</span>';

      $(this).html(strOut);

   });

});
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/xGa2J/2/

Comment: Ugh.. hungarian notation.. will it ever die?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
var header = $('.date-header');
var d = header.text().split('-');
header.html('<span class="dhy">' + d[0] + '</span><span class="dhm">' + d[1] + '</span><span class="dhd">' + d[2] + '</span>');
```

Comment: I'd use `.text() instead of `.html()` in the first line.